# Virtumart one page checkout(vm 2.5)

Tags: joomla, checkout, virtuemart

I have installed virtuemart one page checkout plugin. In vm order is placed first and then its redirected for payment.
I want that payment should be done first and after successful payment order and order mail should be placed. Anyone has idea?
Is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: It depends to the api of your payment method, please add some details about the payment method that you use.

Comment: Hello,

Thanks For the reply. I am using linkpoint payment which is commercial. I have changed the order flow now orders is placed after payment success. But still I am not able found mail function.
After order placed from where mail is being sent.

Let em know if you have any idea.

Answer (score 0):

Virtuemart fire order e-mails due to order status. You could set them at:

```
Virtuemart -> Configuration -> Checkout -> Default Order Status to create an invoice
Virtuemart -> Configuration -> Checkout -> Default Order Status to send email to shopper
```

Adding or removing Order statuses could be done from:

```
Virtuemart -> Order Statuses
```

So your plugin has to set the appropriate status to the order before and after payment to select if mail will be sent or not.

Good Luck!